# Como plotar um gráfico de colunas agrupados com ggplot

Tags: r, gráfico

como posso fazer um gráfico de colunas agrupados por ano? Tenho um banco de dados extenso com várias variáveis e gostaria de plotar um gráfico com separado por ano.
Como fazer? Para algumas variáveis o gráfico está ficando assim, mas ainda não consegui ajustar por ano:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até o momento meu código está assim:

```
ggplot(data=espacial, aes(x=AREAURB_2018, y=microrregião, fill=microrregião))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill=microrregião), stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

Aqui só tem o Efetivo Bovino ([Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/exPNn5rH)):

```
CodMun;microrregião;MUNIC;EFETIVOBOV_2000;EFETIVOBOV_2001;EFETIVOBOV_2002;EFETIVOBOV_2003;EFETIVOBOV_2004;EFETIVOBOV_2005;EFETIVOBOV_2006;EFETIVOBOV_2007;EFETIVOBOV_2008;EFETIVOBOV_2009;EFETIVOBOV_2010;EFETIVOBOV_2011;EFETIVOBOV_2012;EFETIVOBOV_2013;EFETIVOBOV_2014;EFETIVOBOV_2015;EFETIVOBOV_2016;EFETIVOBOV_2017;EFETIVOBOV_2018
1500404,00;Santarém;Alenquer(PA);96000,00;99778,00;120000,00;106080,00;137164,00;151468,00;161306,00;167401,00;112400,00;147352,00;170396,00;166052,00;160908,00;168444,00;191140,00;189902,00;190903,00;188400,00;213741,00
1500503,00;Almeirim;Almeirim(PA);12031,00;18728,00;20600,00;21630,00;22170,00;23278,00;23976,00;25395,00;33108,00;34763,00;36501,00;38326,00;39475,00;25312,00;24124,00;21853,00;21100,00;23414,00;28110,00
1500602,00;Altamira;Altamira(PA);202965,00;203066,00;272839,00;291061,00;314217,00;339517,00;365034,00;402340,00;399512,00;413625,00;555324,00;688901,00;668541,00;711028,00;687535,00;628481,00;657436,00;656430,00;707958,00
1500859,00;Altamira;Anapu(PA);48950,00;83407,00;68747,00;95149,00;118600,00;139260,00;172456,00;280321,00;175384,00;177857,00;171721,00;175023,00;225093,00;270460,00;262642,00;251681,00;267860,00;202400,00;237584,00
1501006,00;SãoFelixdoXingu;Aveiro(PA);14300,00;15000,00;15300,00;19957,00;23450,00;25604,00;30540,00;37329,00;35447,00;37229,00;37736,00;37202,00;31160,00;43637,00;42160,00;45668,00;47187,00;50942,00;50227,00
1501253,00;SãoFelixdoXingu;Bannach(PA);152313,00;191673,00;171374,00;171342,00;257085,00;201557,00;193461,00;165102,00;142813,00;171387,00;192965,00;195272,00;211401,00;193334,00;240905,00;231288,00;240080,00;258244,00;248230,00
1501451,00;Altamira;Belterra(PA);10000,00;11200,00;12650,00;13477,00;21017,00;17730,00;15700,00;9491,00;12200,00;23835,00;21765,00;20729,00;24136,00;26490,00;23843,00;23405,00;20842,00;21310,00;23810,00
1501725,00;Altamira;BrasilNovo(PA);139905,00;196187,00;195748,00;213054,00;245507,00;263254,00;259546,00;225866,00;219847,00;222722,00;206099,00;211000,00;217881,00;235712,00;241027,00;233652,00;240470,00;223901,00;230385,00
1502764,00;SãoFelixdoXingu;CumarudoNorte(PA);195110,00;197062,00;200017,00;213118,00;611151,00;549673,00;550712,00;447412,00;440378,00;588925,00;638983,00;683072,00;749278,00;821185,00;743174,00;772554,00;808396,00;846495,00;807787,00
1502855,00;Santarém;Curuá(PA);11960,00;13395,00;14735,00;22000,00;25000,00;18674,00;26646,00;29868,00;28286,00;26020,00;32647,00;34034,00;32109,00;32181,00;34433,00;37187,00;37148,00;44068,00;44924,00
1503002,00;Óbidos;Faro(PA);3890,00;3306,00;4138,00;5793,00;6372,00;7646,00;8500,00;13937,00;9226,00;7934,00;7457,00;871,00;1019,00;12149,00;10966,00;11318,00;12109,00;13102,00;9757,00
1503606,00;Itaituba;Itaituba(PA);146000,00;140000,00;151200,00;168641,00;180160,00;243759,00;270698,00;174318,00;267526,00;270657,00;309894,00;325567,00;337737,00;360703,00;344197,00;331381,00;328979,00;368776,00;343981,00
1503754,00;Itaituba;Jacareacanga(PA);22700,00;25000,00;26250,00;30187,00;5165,00;6802,00;8467,00;26789,00;26250,00;27038,00;12992,00;12993,00;15602,00;16085,00;15396,00;14716,00;14468,00;80476,00;81350,00
1503903,00;Óbidos;Juruti(PA);40500,00;46575,00;46575,00;50000,00;48500,00;32000,00;43627,00;38906,00;43254,00;37198,00;29758,00;30137,00;40996,00;21745,00;28441,00;27872,00;31486,00;40347,00;42608,00
1504455,00;Altamira;Medicilândia(PA);49175,00;70323,00;105443,00;111910,00;124373,00;137864,00;157128,00;143359,00;135117,00;134380,00;103939,00;123212,00;133885,00;143371,00;152562,00;158768,00;165016,00;166100,00;147540,00
1504802,00;Santarém;MonteAlegre(PA);100000,00;106761,00;114706,00;171865,00;174302,00;177451,00;196200,00;128412,00;191680,00;191680,00;186473,00;192242,00;205728,00;214596,00;219112,00;221942,00;214361,00;236968,00;244500,00
1505031,00;Itaituba;NovoProgresso(PA);155974,00;185000,00;183568,00;231741,00;378573,00;463784,00;561628,00;105989,00;412400,00;763088,00;636227,00;680671,00;687142,00;632521,00;590273,00;567077,00;579218,00;618365,00;618876,00
1505106,00;Óbidos;Óbidos(PA);85681,00;100681,00;120817,00;126857,00;120000,00;128394,00;124526,00;127768,00;125428,00;113090,00;120713,00;127269,00;127687,00;127269,00;129823,00;133551,00;133989,00;143462,00;143128,00
1505304,00;Óbidos;Oriximiná(PA);102184,00;78638,00;82842,00;91486,00;104000,00;131563,00;123430,00;131525,00;130485,00;139852,00;135156,00;125350,00;147748,00;159623,00;140549,00;141576,00;140340,00;148328,00;139429,00
1505437,00;SãoFelixdoXingu;OurilândiadoNorte(PA);156078,00;188993,00;194656,00;207877,00;202944,00;216980,00;198936,00;103510,00;173569,00;158221,00;181515,00;191113,00;194935,00;187148,00;191441,00;181074,00;186959,00;204229,00;192522,00
1505486,00;Altamira;Pacajá(PA);97345,00;138319,00;166542,00;250643,00;283204,00;313579,00;334595,00;256420,00;370333,00;415724,00;400216,00;358037,00;432578,00;492442,00;536460,00;573471,00;585925,00;643200,00;620785,00
1505650,00;Santarém;Placas(PA);68000,00;62000,00;50142,00;62756,00;66257,00;74174,00;78658,00;59450,00;87605,00;90381,00;90823,00;72122,00;102831,00;116124,00;127830,00;132387,00;135286,00;140977,00;140480,00
1505908,00;Almeirim;PortodeMoz(PA);9516,00;12850,00;17850,00;18742,00;20451,00;20241,00;20853,00;47913,00;48215,00;51107,00;53662,00;56077,00;57759,00;20278,00;50030,00;46670,00;51433,00;52918,00;46893,00
1506005,00;Santarém;Prainha(PA);62609,00;63861,00;65138,00;66440,00;79581,00;95497,00;100986,00;102125,00;113821,00;115630,00;121412,00;127482,00;131306,00;114548,00;119353,00;110494,00;114728,00;123652,00;110253,00
1506195,00;SãoFelixdoXingu;Rurópolis(PA);50000,00;50000,00;57962,00;59599,00;88226,00;105872,00;115984,00;117821,00;102000,00;112044,00;114000,00;116907,00;123990,00;136626,00;142087,00;145251,00;152471,00;159930,00;158534,00
1506807,00;Santarém;Santarém(PA);105332,00;100000,00;95000,00;106088,00;153115,00;133218,00;126935,00;104529,00;130613,00;116503,00;132008,00;118861,00;138911,00;129954,00;132300,00;115052,00;113620,00;118897,00;120537,00
1507300,00;SãoFelixdoXingu;SãoFélixdoXingu(PA);682407,00;1030019,00;1157707,00;1264991,00;1527017,00;1581518,00;1596411,00;1653231,00;1812870,00;1912009,00;2022366,00;2101726,00;2143760,00;2282445,00;2213310,00;2222949,00;2200338,00;2240496,00;2256734,00
1507805,00;Altamira;SenadorJoséPorfírio(PA);12742,00;21385,00;26938,00;30900,00;36546,00;45432,00;57396,00;60899,00;48105,00;52427,00;44467,00;57029,00;64208,00;68790,00;70379,00;73405,00;71425,00;70300,00;79920,00
1507979,00;Óbidos;TerraSanta(PA);41541,00;47772,00;57326,00;60192,00;50000,00;52000,00;35000,00;40000,00;47178,00;39157,00;38373,00;25000,00;27325,00;36672,00;35419,00;30133,00;33442,00;36177,00;29557,00
1508050,00;SãoFelixdoXingu;Trairão(PA);20400,00;25000,00;27000,00;28753,00;36686,00;44053,00;53815,00;68497,00;46972,00;65262,00;77972,00;86865,00;86478,00;96839,00;96562,00;95934,00;102281,00;108399,00;106543,00
1508084,00;SãoFelixdoXingu;Tucumã(PA);344136,00;341604,00;355781,00;349637,00;372073,00;359975,00;315622,00;175778,00;291651,00;284979,00;268172,00;274254,00;282481,00;282064,00;283818,00;284593,00;305524,00;329551,00;332269,00
1508159,00;Altamira;Uruará(PA);95345,00;125207,00;158723,00;193905,00;232912,00;250739,00;295527,00;293640,00;291868,00;297341,00;290513,00;288172,00;298960,00;308125,00;313523,00;310109,00;280603,00;205800,00;271258,00
1508357,00;Altamira;VitóriadoXingu(PA);127520,00;166720,00;195642,00;235526,00;245590,00;250002,00;220292,00;195201,00;193924,00;195155,00;169964,00;152217,00;175376,00;166290,00;156564,00;146937,00;135543,00;121600,00;122015,00
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este tipo de problema geralmente está relacionado à reformatação dos dados. O formato deve ser longo e os dados estão em formato largo. Veja [esta postagem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) sobre como reformatar os dados do formato largo para o longo.

No código abaixo segui os seguintes passos.

1. Filtrar as colunas sem `microrregião`;
2. Reformatar os dados para o formato longo;
3. Criar um gráfico base e guardá-lo na variável `p`.

Depois é só acrescentar a `geom_*` requerida (`geom_col` ou `geom_bar`) e melhorar o aspeto final, tal como pedido [neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/509609/como-plotar-um-gr%c3%a1fico-de-colunas-agrupados-com-ggplot#comment936111_509631) à resposta do [@abreums](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/509631/82237). A rotação dos anos no eixo dos x vem dessa resposta.

---

#### Reformatar os dados e criar o objeto gráfico.

```
library(tidyverse)

espacial %>%
  filter(microrregião != "") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("EFETIVOBOV"),
    names_to = "Ano",
    values_to = "Efetivo"
  ) %>%
  mutate(Ano = str_extract(Ano, "\\d+")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Ano, y = Efetivo, fill = microrregião)) +
  labs(y = "Efetivo Bovino") -> p
```

---

#### Barras sobrepostas.

```
p + geom_col() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Barras lado a lado.

```
p + geom_col(position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rui, deu certinho para todas as variáveis. Obrigada pela explicação!!!

Answer (score 2):

...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

dt <- read_csv2("ImportacaoR.txt")

# é preciso "pivotar" / "rodar" os dados 
# para que haja uma coluna com os anos e outra com os efetivos
dt <- dt %>% 
  pivot_longer(EFETIVOBOV_2000:EFETIVOBOV_2018, 
               names_to = "ano", 
               values_to = "efetivo")

# vamos subtrair "EFETIVOBOV" da coluna "ano" (criada acima) 
# e transformar em inteiro
dt <- dt %>% 
  mutate(ano = as.integer(str_sub(ano, -4, -1)))

# gráfico empilhando os efetivos por ano para todos os municípios
dt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ano, 
             y = efetivo, 
             group = microrregião, 
             fill = microrregião)) +
  geom_col() +
  # limita os "breaks" do eixo x
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016)) + 
  # acrescenta separador nos valores do eixo y
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format(big.mark = ".",
                                                   decimal.mark = ",")) +
  # inclinação para o texto do eixo x + ajuste horizontal 
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  ) +
  labs( 
    title = "Aumento do efetivo de cabeças de gado no PA",
    subtitle = "2000 - 2018",
    x = "Ano",
    y = "Efetivo"
  ) 


# outro gráfico separando os efetivos por município 
# em gráficos diferentes - facet_wrap
dt %>%
  # alguns registros não contém informação de microrregião, 
  # por isso incluimos este filtro para evitar o facet de NA 
  filter(!is.na(microrregião)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ano, 
             y = efetivo, 
             group = microrregião, 
             fill = microrregião)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000, 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016)) + 
  # acrescenta separador nos valores do eixo
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format(big.mark = ".",
                                                   decimal.mark = ",")) +
  theme(
    # inclinação para o texto do eixo x + ajuste horizontal 
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    # esconde a legenda
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  labs( title = "Aumento do efetivo de cabeças de gado no PA",
        subtitle = "2000 - 2018",
        x = element_blank(),
        y = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~ microrregião)
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta! Queria tirar uma dúvida, é possível organizar os rótulos abaixo do gráfico (o de anos)? Eles ficaram sobrepostos

Comment: Depois eu vi que vc queria por microrregião e eu fiz por município... arrumei isto também.

Comment: ótimo, abreu! Aqui ficou com duas colunas, ao invés de 18, você sabe o que pode ter ocorrido? Abraços

Comment: Talvez porque estamos usando bases diferentes. Acrescentei a linha que usei para ler o arquivo q vc enviou. Eu precisaria de mais informações para poder ajudar mais.

Comment: Obrigada mesmo Abreu!